# Авторизация vk.com с использованием QWebView

Tags: qt, vkontakte-api, qt5

При попытке отобразить запрос авторизации к VK с помощью  метода `load()` класса `QWebView` отображается лишь белое окно. Если изменить url на любой другой, то без проблем отображается, а вот окно авторизации не хочет.
Пример кода:

```
QWebView* view = new QWebView;
view->load (QUrl ("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1234567&scope=wall,offline&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token"));
view->show ();
```

**Вопрос:** Собственно можно ли передавать в качестве параметра в метод load запрос такого вида и если нет, то каким образом делать запрос?
Я использую Qt 5.0.2
.

*Update:* Этот код работает нормально на Qt 4

Answer (score 1):

Я делал авторизацию для ВКашной либы правда на PyQt4, но суть одна и та же по сути
посмотри вот [тут](https://github.com/alexandr-nino/social-api/blob/master/vk/OAuth.py)
и [тут](https://github.com/alexandr-nino/social-api/blob/master/vk/__init__.py) как генерируется строка запроса для окна авторизации, или просто попробуй заменить у себя `page` на `popup`

Comment: Примерно так я уже пытался делать, видимо вся проблема в портировании кода в QT 5.
Пробовал и через QUrlQuery результат один и тот же.
    QUrlQuery urlQuery = QUrlQuery();
    QUrl url = QUrl("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize");
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("client_id", appid);
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("scope", "wall,offline");
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("redirect_uri",     "http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html");
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("display", "page");
    urlQuery.addQueryItem("response_type", "token");
    url.setQuery (urlQuery);
    this->load (url);
    this->show();

Answer (score -2):

```
view->load(QUrl("http://vk.com/"));
```

убрал `https` и все загрузилось

**Обновление**

```
view->load (QUrl ("http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3682744&v=5.7&scope=wall,offline&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token"));
```

вот на Qt 5.5 у меня загрузилась страница авторизации

Comment: ну да фигню сморозил